# Asynchronous query in PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, guzzle6

I would like to perform an asynchronous query in PHP without waiting for a response back

- when I execute this code, the request is not sent. what to do. I would like it to be without waiting for an answer.
- I use guzzle

```
    $data="";
        foreach($postData as $key=>$value){
            if($data==""){
                $data.='?'.$key.'='.$value;
            }else{
                $data.='&'.$key.'='.$value;
            }
        }
        $data=$gsValues['URL_ROOT'].'func/fn_update_column.php'.$data;
        //$url=urlencode(rtrim($data));
        $url=rtrim($data);
        $client = new Client();
        $param = array(
            'order_id' => 4544,
            'type' => 0,
            'amount' => 1266,
            'fullname' => 'qdxeq',
            'account' => 'dqad',
            'callback_url' => 'http://yuexingy.top/Withdraw/WithdrawCallback.aspx',
            'device_type' => 'dqd',
            'device_id' => 'dafwe',
            'device_ip' => 'dwe',
        );

        $json = json_encode($param);
        $data = array('json'=>$json);
        $req = new Request('POST',$url, $param);
        $client->sendAsync($req);
```

When I execute this code, the request is not sent. what to do. I would like it to be without waiting for an answer.

Comment: This shall help http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/faq.html#can-guzzle-send-asynchronous-requests

Comment: are you sure your request is not sent?

Comment: I used this documentation to write my script but my request is not sent. it compels me to code a promise that it can be sent

Comment: Giacomo M. Yes. the request is not sent. when I proceed as below. the request is sent.$promise = $client->sendAsync($req,['timeout' => 10])->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});
$promise->wait();